# set multiple google map coordinates Objects inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I want to store latitude and longitude of points inside an object, and all my objects inside an array. But my array get each object more than one time.

**This is my code :**

```
function initMap1() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('frame1');
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv,{
    center: {lat: 3.875083, lng: 11.516110},
    zoom: 14,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true
  }); 
  var Data = [];
  google.maps.event.addListener(map,'dblclick',function(e){
    var Object = {};
    lat.val(e.latLng.lat());
    lng.val(e.latLng.lng());
    $('#btn_modal').click(function(){
      Object['lat'] = e.latLng.lat();
      Object['lng'] = e.latLng.lng();
      Object['icone'] = nat.val();
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat:e.latLng.lat(),lng:e.latLng.lng()},
        map: map,
        icon:'img/icones/'+(nat.val())+'.png',
        title: nat.val()
      });
    });
    Data.push(Object);
  });
}
```

Comment: You are attaching a click event to a button when you double click on the google map.  That seems weird, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: A bootstrap modal appear when i double click on the map.And that modal frame contain a button which enable me to store my coordinates inside an Object and the Object inside my array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push your object to the data array when you click your modal button, then you should move the push call inside the event you are creating.  Otherwise your object gets pushed to the array every time you double click the map.

Instead of

```
$('#btn_modal').click(function(){
            Object['lat'] = e.latLng.lat();
            Object['lng'] = e.latLng.lng();
            Object['icone'] = nat.val();
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat:e.latLng.lat(),lng:e.latLng.lng()},
                map: map,
                icon:'img/icones/'+(nat.val())+'.png',
                title: nat.val()
            });
        });
        Data.push(Object);
```

make it

```
$('#btn_modal').click(function(){
            Object['lat'] = e.latLng.lat();
            Object['lng'] = e.latLng.lng();
            Object['icone'] = nat.val();
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat:e.latLng.lat(),lng:e.latLng.lng()},
                map: map,
                icon:'img/icones/'+(nat.val())+'.png',
                title: nat.val()
            });
     ----> Data.push(Object);
        });
```

Comment: I did it but the result is the same. My array got my first coordinate's point more than one time.

Comment: I also reset my object after setting its content inside the array, but nothing has changed.... My code is still not working like i expect it to work.

Comment: Have you used developer tools in the browser to set a breakpoint in your JavaScript, or tried any other client side debugging techniques?

Comment: Yes. I try to debug it, but it's going wrong again.